# Django admin add extra fields in list

Tags: django, django-admin, django-queryset

In my project i have a table with a foreign key to another one.
In django admin i would to display fields from the two tables.
This is my original model:

```
class t_time(models.Model):
    history_main = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    elapsed_t = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6, default=Decimal('0.0000'))
```

in admin.py i try to make a query fro extract and add to my view extra fields from the tables but probably i was wrong in some point. I try to override get_queryset like this:

```
class t_timeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','hist_data','elapsed_t')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        myqs = t_history.objects.get(id=t_time.history_main)
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            _hist_data=myqs.test_type,
            #_villain_count=Count("villain", distinct=True),
        )
        return queryset

    def hist_data(self, obj):
        return obj._hist_data
```

but i get an error about a returned type (int) that probably is related to annotate() directive.
How can i add extra field from a query to my django admin view?

So many thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect the issue is `t_history.objects.get(id=t_time.history_main)`. Django would expect an `int` for the id, but `t_time.history_main` is a field.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way you can aproach your issue, using OneToOneFields.

models.py

```
class DataModel(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name

    def two_fields(self):
        id = self.id
        field1 = ModelData.objects.get(connected_table_id=id).data1
        field2 = ModelData.objects.get(connected_table_id=id).data2
        return '%s %s' % (field1, field2)


class ModelData(models.Model):
    data1 = models.IntegerField()
    data2 = models.IntegerField()
    connected_table = models.OneToOneField(DataModel,
                                           related_name="DataModel",
                                           on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                           )

    def extramethod(self):
        code = self.connected_table_id
        format_code = DataModel.objects.get(id=code).name
        return format_code
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(ModelData)
class ModelDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'data1', 'data2', 'connected_table', 'extramethod',)

@admin.register(DataModel)
class ModelDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'two_fields',)
```